# C# and MySql integration

Tags: c#, mysql

How well does C# integrate with MySQL ?

I am planning to write a small desktop application that connects to a Database and displays records. Is C# and MySQL a good combination ?

Should I use Java Swings and MySQL ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ralph Stevens suggested, you'd better go with SQL Server 2008 Express. Visual Studio 2008 integrates neatly with it and can generate Linq To Sql plumbing code right off the database. With a few clicks you are ready to handle the database in every way imaginable.

If you code ASP .NET, there is an added benefit: The mdf file that contains the actual database information can be stored in the App_Data folder and that goes with the project itself rather than the database engine. That comes in handly when you distribute the code to coworkers.

MySQL would work just as well with its .NET Connector but you will lose the visual benefits.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. You can use [MySQL .Net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706205/c-and-mysql-integration/1706222#1706222).

Or better, you use ORM ( such as [NHIbernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)) to abstract away the database vendor. I use NHibernate with MySQL in my C# application and it works well.

Comment: +1 for using an ORM; as well as NHibernate, I've used http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/default.aspx to work with MySQL using C#/.NET, and I know many of the other .NET ORMs also support it.

Answer (score 1):

They integrate quite well. You can use ODBC, or better yet, the new [MySQL .Net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

May be this links be use full for you, was for me, when I started :)

[windows-programming.suite101.com](http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/how_to_access_mysql_with_c) and 
[bitdaddys.com](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html)

Answer (score 0):

How big is your database requirement? .NET works much better with SQL Server. SQL Server Express can go up to 4 Gigs of data and it's free. It meets the requirements of most small to medium apps. I suggest SQL Server Express.

Comment: Mate my DB is going to be very small may be a 100 Mb. 4 Gigs is a lot of data :-) Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into SQL Server Express.