# Including SQL Server Express Advanced 2012 in the prerequisites of a setup project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, prerequisites

We created a setup project in VS2010.

Can you tell us how to add SQL Server Express Advanced 2012 into the prerequisites list of the   prerequisites dialog box in a setup project?

We see the 2008 version, but not the 2012 version is the list.

This is the first time doing a setup project like this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095462/visual-studio-windows-installer-with-mysql-check-and-install) is a similar question

It's the same approach: create a custom prerequisite.